The box are not consistent in height after being compiled into an APK on Windows
On the online dartpad platform or during debugging on the Windows operating system, the application performs well with no apparent issues. In these environments, all component heights are consistent, for instance, the standard text input box and the drop-down menu-based text input box (DropDownTextField) have almost the same height.
However, when I build and install this app on an Android device, some unexplainable issues occur. Specifically, the heights of various components differ. The most concrete example is that the standard text input box appears to be somewhat taller than the drop-down menu-based text input box (DropDownTextField).
Furthermore, if a suffix is added to the text box, this height difference becomes even more noticeable. Specifically, the text input box with a suffix appears to be taller than other input boxes.
All this has left me puzzled, as I can't figure out what is going on. I have tried testing in online and Windows environments, but this issue seems to only surface on Android devices. It's been troubling me for a long time, and despite my attempts to find answers, I have come up empty-handed. Does anyone know what could be causing this? I desperately need your help.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

Widget buildInputField(BuildContext context, TextEditingController controller,
    double width, String label,
    {String suffix = ""}) {
  return SizedBox(
    width: width,
    height: 60,
    child: TextField(
      controller: controller,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: label,
        suffixText: suffix,
        border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
        contentPadding:
            const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15.0, horizontal: 10.0),
      ),
      inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
        FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r'^-?\d*\.?\d*')),
      ],
      keyboardType: const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
    ),
  );
}

class DropDownTextField extends StatefulWidget {
  final TextEditingController? controller;
  final List<String> items;
  final String label;
  final String? suffix;
  final String? initialValue;
  final double? width;
  final void Function(String)? onChanged;
  final bool isEditable;

  const DropDownTextField({
    super.key,
    this.controller,
    required this.items,
    required this.label,
    this.suffix,
    this.initialValue,
    this.width,
    this.onChanged,
    this.isEditable = true,
  });

  @override
  State<DropDownTextField> createState() => _DropDownTextFieldState();
}

class _DropDownTextFieldState extends State<DropDownTextField> {
  late TextEditingController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = widget.controller ?? TextEditingController();
    _controller.text = widget.initialValue ?? '';
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      if (mounted && widget.initialValue != null && widget.onChanged != null) {
        widget.onChanged!(widget.initialValue!);
      }
    });
  }

  void _onSelected(String value) {
    _controller.text = value;
    if (widget.onChanged != null) {
      widget.onChanged!(value);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: widget.width,
      height: 60,
      child: TextField(
        controller: _controller,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          labelText: widget.label,
          suffixText: widget.suffix,
          border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
          contentPadding:
              const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15.0, horizontal: 10.0),
          suffixIcon: PopupMenuButton<String>(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
            onSelected: _onSelected,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
              return widget.items.map<PopupMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                return PopupMenuItem(
                  value: value,
                  child: Text(value),
                );
              }).toList();
            },
          ),
        ),
        onChanged: widget.onChanged,
        readOnly: !widget.isEditable,
        keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    if (widget.controller == null) {
      _controller.dispose();
    }
    super.dispose();
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: DropDownTextFieldExample(),
    );
  }
}

class DropDownTextFieldExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const DropDownTextFieldExample({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  DropDownTextFieldExampleState createState() =>
      DropDownTextFieldExampleState();
}

class DropDownTextFieldExampleState extends State<DropDownTextFieldExample> {
  final TextEditingController textController1 = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController textController2 = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController textController3 = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController textController4 = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('DropDownTextField Example'),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: DropDownTextField(
                    controller: textController1,
                    items: ['Option 1', 'Option 2', 'Option 3'],
                    label: 'Label1',
                    initialValue: 'Option 1',
                    isEditable: false,
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: buildInputField(context, textController2, 100, 'Input',
                      suffix: "suffix"),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: DropDownTextField(
                    controller: textController3,
                    items: ['Option 1', 'Option 2', 'Option 3'],
                    label: 'Label3',
                    isEditable: false,
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: buildInputField(context, textController4, 100, 'Input',
                      ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}



I have tried some changes, but it not work.
